# Recover Deleted Branch Git

Tags: git

I have a huge issue that i need to solve (If it can be solved)

I have accidentally deleted a branch from local and from GitHub and would like to recover the work. However, where the problem lies is that I had not committed the work before it was deleted.

Is this still recoverable and how??

Cheers

Comment: If you have deleted stuff which you have not yet committed, git won't be able to help you. It only tracks data you have committed.

Comment: Can you check the git status? Are the files still uncommitted and changed?

Comment: @holgerJust I looked at this but assumed it was changes that had already been committed. I have just ran the command using the sha1 for the most recent entry in the reflog and everything is back to how it should be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @demonLaMagra : to make your question clearer : you had actually *committed* your work locally, but hadn't *pushed* to gitub, right ?

Comment: @LeGEC I didn't believe I had but must of to have had it all put back together. I'm pretty new to Git so I do apologise for being Naïve.